# Nested List Comprehension With Flow Control

Tags: python, list-comprehension, primes

I am attempting to write the following code as a one-liner.

```
for x in range(a, b+1):
   prime = True
   for y in range(2, int(x**0.5)):
     if x%y == 0:
       prime = False
       break
   if prime:
     return x
```

This is searching for prime numbers between a and b. I will saving each prime number into a list. The code above above is checking each number in the range for primality. The problem is that I must write this nested loop as a one-line list comprehension. The problem I have is that the list comprehension will not go through the second loop. It will check with 2, then pop out of the loop.

I tried this approach, and it failed miserably:
         `([x for x in range(10, 21) for y in range(2, int(x**0.5)) if x%y != 0])`

Comment: They code you've shown doesn't many any sense. `next` is a builtin function that you can call on an iterator, it's not a statement as you seem to be using it here. Do you perhaps mean `continue`? That's a statement, though it won't continue the outer loop which I think your algorithm requires in order to work properly. You could make it work using `break` in the `if` and putting the `return` line in an `else` block attached to the inner `for` loop (a weird bit of Python syntax).

Comment: Why do you think it "pops" out of the loop?  The line of code you present will not produce any visible output.  The part of your code inside square brackets is a list comprehension, which you would typically bind to a variable name.  Then you can print it, for example, and only then will you see whether there is anything in it.

Comment: Why would you write it as a list comprehension? You don't want a list; you want a single value.

Comment: @chepner I want ALL the primes in a range. The code above is applied to every number in that range as a filter function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Prime_numbers_list = [x for x in range(a, b+1) 
                      if all(x%y !=0 for y in range(2, int(x**0.5)))]
```

Comment: x/2 is not the same as x**0.5.

Comment: This works perfectly! I did not know about the all function. That is very helpful.

Comment: @ddcastrodd, I don't believe a *perfect* list of primes includes 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 15, 25, 35, etc. which this code currently produces when I run it.  The bug is `int(x**0.5)` should be `int(x**0.5) + 1` as it's the end point of a range.

Comment: That's right. I added +1 when running it myself, but the gist of the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would build an inner list of modular results, and check if there are any zeros:

```
[x for x in range(10, 21) if 0 not in (x%y for y in range(2, int(x**0.5)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intention correctly, you're trying to find the smallest prime between `a` and `b` in a single line. You have some current code, but what you've shown doesn't make any sense. I think the logic you were attempting to show could work like this:

```
def find_prime_between(a, b):
    for x in range(a, b+1):
        for y in range(2, int(x**0.5)):
            if x%y == 0:
                break
        else:
            return x
```

One way to turn this into a one-liner is to use the `all` builtin function. It can replace the inner loop, including the short-circuting behavior that came from the `break` and `else` blocks. For the outer loop, I'd suggest using calling `next` on a generator, which gets the first value yielded by the generator:

```
result = next(x for x in range(a, b+1) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, int(x**0.5))))
```

By default `next` will raise `StopIteration` if the generator doesn't yield anything (because there are no primes between `a` and `b`). If you want it to return some other value (such as `None`) in that situation, you can pass it as a second argument to `next`. That will require the generator expression to be wrapped in parentheses, since it's not the only argument:

```
result = next((x for x in range(a, b+1) if all(x%y!=0 for y in range(2, int(x**0.5)))), None)
```

That takes a bit of squeezing to fit onto a single line in this answer without a scroll bar.